# Script to show directories information

Tags: ubuntu, scripting

Trying to figure out a command/script I can use to view a directories:

- folder size summary/total files, that's human readable
- free and used disk space of the directory
- info on when the script was run (time/date)

I have to insert it into an apache page about a directory that I have on my local server. I keep seeing du brought up and with `du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr` I just get the size and the directory names which is only about 25% of what I need.

Sort of lost here, any clues or ideas as to how I may be able to accomplish this?

Comment: A directory doesn't really have free space; that attribute belongs to a filesystem. See `df` (`man df` for documentation). I don't see a difference between "_used disk space of the directory_" and the first requirement. The third requirement may be satisfied by the `date` command

Comment: Since this is more about a dynamically generated web page, I think it might be safer to use PHP rather than CGI.